# set shape background to transparent in android

Tags: android, android-layout, transparency, xml-drawable

I have a shape drawable that I want to use as a background. I want the shape to be transparent. But so far it's not. How do I do that? Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#80000000" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

I expected the line `<solid android:color="#80000000" />` to do the trick.

EDIT:

In manifest, I set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`. Could that be the cause of the problem? I am basically trying to get this view on top of another. Changing to 00 or FF or whatever else does not work.

Comment: Do you want the alpha value to be 80?  Is that intentional?  Or did you want it to have zero opacity, 00?

Comment: please add code where you set background to view.

Answer (score 21):

if you want set shape background to transparent you need to set this color

```
<solid android:color="#00000000" />
```

Answer (score 11):

for creating a color including an opacity effect, you can create a color
with taking the alpha channel into account.

```
<resources>
<color name="translucent_grey">#88cccccc</color>
</resources>
```

a quote from another User about the color formats:

> When defining the color of a view in android, the format can be either #RRGGBB or #AARRGGBB, where AA is the hex alpha value. FF would be fully opaque and 00 would be full transparent.

more information about this technique can be found in this thread:
[How to Set Opacity (Alpha) for View in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android)

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 8):

You can use this :

```
<solid
    android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. Direct quote:

The easiest way that I have found is to set the activity's theme in the AndroidManifest to android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" then in the activity's onCreate method call getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

from @DrewLeonce in [Android: how to create a transparent dialog-themed activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070505/android-how-to-create-a-transparent-dialog-themed-activity)