# android semi dialog semi activity - activity with dialog style, fullscreen dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

I'm working on my small app and I have terrible problem with dialogs. Partially my question will be technical, partially general.

For example I have the following scenario: 1) user select file type 2) user select file 3) user select some additional options - list of about 5/6 options.

I'm wondering if to do this as some kind of three steps wizard (for each step separate dialog) either as one activity with three buttons/elements for selecting the appropriate elements. How do you think? I would like to have my app giving some kind of light appearance to users, thus I would prefer not to have heavy things. have you seen any good examples of more complicated dialogs/activities? Any official guide for more complicated dialogs?

Moreover some technical questions:
1) Is that possible to have activity (full screen) looking as dialog (style)? If yes, how?
2) As for now I use DialogFragment. However android by default sets its dimensions in the way that there is no need to resize them when changing screen orientation (screen smaller dimension is the base for setting dialog size). In consequence when having screen in vertical orientation huge part of screen is not used by dialog. How to change that to have dialog occuping almost the whole screen, but also resizing correctly when changing screen orientation and if possible with still keeping setRetainInstance(true) (less problems with dialogs when changing orientation)?

Comment: set a non dialog theme to your dialog fragment

Comment: FTR when I was asking another question, I have a full example of that in the question here .. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23848285/294884

Answer (score 0):

use the following line of code in your activity below  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
```

refer following link,

[Android: how to create a transparent dialog-themed activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070505/android-how-to-create-a-transparent-dialog-themed-activity)