# How to create layout with transparent background?

Tags: android, layout, background

I am a beginner developer android. I write a layout for my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Google sign-in"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/passPrompt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"/>
    <!-- android:text="@string/pass1" --> 


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/unTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="Username"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>


 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonbg"
    android:layout_width="286dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- android:background="@color/grey" -->

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Sign in" />

</LinearLayout>
```

when running my code, I get my layout like as right side in image in [here](http://www.imghack.se/187989).
But I want a layout like as left side image.
How I can transparent my background theme?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070505/android-how-to-create-a-transparent-dialog-themed-activity , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: You mean the "You entered the wrong password..." text is missing?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan, I saw your links before, but they don't work for me. can I chat with U?

Comment: yes, what is the problem with that code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the layout that you want to make transparent:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

I use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="onBackPressed" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="onBackPressed" />

    <!-- add your layout here -->

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="onBackPressed" />

</LinearLayout> 

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="onBackPressed" />
```